# Does false vacuum necessarily have negative pressure?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, pressure, vacuum, cosmological-inflation

Inflation theory suggests that false vacuum must negative pressure to create a repulsive gravitational effect which drives space expansion.

Why would false vacuum have negative pressure? Or is it assumed to be so just to fit the Inflation theory?

Comment: What happens when you solve the continuity equation for constant energy density?

Comment: @bapowell If the energy density is constant, the pressure must be negative. But what I’m asking is : Does false vacuum necessarily  have negative pressure?

Comment: What is the energy density of false vacuum? Is it constant?

Comment: @bapowell I will try to answer as a layman:)  Energy density is constant if the pressure is negative. But why do we think that false vacuum has negative pressure?

Comment: Your reasoning is backwards: false vacuum has negative pressure because it has constant or nearly constant energy density.  As an example of a false vacuum, we can have in mind a 1st order phase transition, where the field is sitting at a metastable equilibrium with $V''(\phi) > 0$.  While it sits there, the potential energy $V(\phi) = const$ and the kinetic energy is zero, and so $\rho = KE + V(\phi) = const$.

Comment: I'm amazed at how many people here are absolutely zealously convinced of $\Lambda CDM$ but haven't got a rudimentary grasp of the foundations of the theory.  This is a perfectly legitimate question with no responses.  'False' vacuum, what the hell is that?  Negative pressure?  how does that not result in a negative temperature?

Comment: @bapowell - Please explain how you can expand the volume of something exponentially and keep a constant energy density?  That requires creating energy by a power of 3 as the volume increases.  If this energy has a wavelength, then it would be a factor of 4.  Einstein said that Thermodynamics is the one theory he thought would last forever.  Have you found a loophole?

Comment: @DonaldAirey: Have I found a loophole? No, this is standard general relativity.  You seem to be unaware that energy is not conserved in general relativity, and so fluids with $\dot{\rho}>0$ are permissible. So are equations of state $p = w\rho$ with $w <0$, i.e. fluids with negative pressure.  For someone so evidently unapprised of the basics of inflation, LCDM, and general relativity, you sure come out swinging.  I recommend an afternoon on wikipedia.

Comment: @bapowell - Let's start with an easy one.  How does a negative pressure not result in a negative temperature.  Did you modify the Ideal Gas Law?

Comment: It does, in that an increase in volume (and hence energy) causes a decrease in entropy.  See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/746f/0dc1515856204edb4ff3dccb81e2787bbe2b.pdf.  For more on negative pressures in cosmology, have a look here: http://discovermagazine.com/2003/mar/featscienceof. Again, not something I came up with (though if I did realize the significance of negative pressures in cosmology, I'd be tenured at MIT right now).